# Вызов метода другого класса

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Продолжение прошлого вопроса.

Есть 2 класса. Нужно в во 2 классе,выполнить метод из 1.
Сам метод:

```
    public void FLYNOTE_refresh(){
        SharedPreferences Pref = getSharedPreferences("nnote", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        key = Pref.getInt("number", 0); 
        String lv_arr[] = new String[key];
        for (int i = 0; i < key; i++){
    lv_arr[i] = Pref.getString("n" + i, "none");
    noten = i;
          }
          textView1.setText(String.valueOf(key));

    listView1.setAdapter(
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
    listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

Как я его вызываю:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.FLYNOTE_refresh();
```

Приложение выкидывает ошибку.

Классы выглядят так (весь код класса кидать не буду,слишком много его):

```
public class Newnote extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

и

```
public class Client extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Comment: а старый вопрос не судьба было отредактировать? Это во первых. Во вторых первый раз вижу чтобы экземпляр активити ТАК создавался. В третьих я так понимаю FLYNOTE_refresh принадлежит классу Newnote? В таком случае, исходя из того что вы пытаетесь сделать мне вас жаль. Не трогайте пока андроид и джаву, почитайте про Си или Паскаль

Comment: а чего про си и паскаль то читать? как это поможет? Тогда уж по джаве лучше и читать тех же Хорстманна и Корнелла

Comment: Вопрос - зачем ты это делаешь?

Comment: @Gorets скорее всего какой-то велосипед, подобный startActivityForResult

Хотя зачем инстанс Client тогда вообще не понятно, тогда неужели это передача данных между активити? О_О

Comment: Врятли, по коды видно, что он пробует из одного активити обновить данные да другом, причем невидимом

Comment: дак и при чем только созданном

Comment: @Gorets ну может конечно быть, что верхняя активити прозрачная, но зачем делать это так, ума не приложу.

Comment: Вот я не пойму как он может быть прозрачной, если тут прямо написано, что он ее только создает в коде.

    Client client = new Client();

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на правильность, но попробую изложить свои мысли

Скорее всего ничего не инициализировано в классе Client (конструктор пустой, не так ли?)

Подозреваю вся логика инициализации лежит в OnCreate() и все элементы управления у вас null'ы

А вообще по-моему какой-то странный архитектурный подход

PS скорее всего Activity должна быть связана с контекстом